# Prove $\exists! A \ni C$ satisfying $C\subseteq P(A)$ and $ \forall X[C \subseteq P(X)\mapsto A\subseteq X]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

> Let $C$ be a set of sets.
> Prove that there is a unique set $A$ satisfying the following properties:

> A) $C\subseteq P(A)$

> B) $ \forall X[C \subseteq P(X) \mapsto A\subseteq X]$

Help me answering this question and where can I find questions like this or be better at analyzing these type of proofs?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Maths stackexchange, your picture wasn't uploaded. Also share your work, what you have tried... just asking help for a question isn't well recieved, for more info go [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For there is a unique set A s.t. $C\subseteq P(A)$:

For every member $c\in C$:

$C\subseteq P(A)\iff  (c\in C\implies c\in P(A))$

This in turn implies that:
$c\subseteq A$

Since:
$c\in P(A)\iff c\subseteq A$

But the smallest set including  $c$ is $c$, since $c\subseteq c$.

Thus:

$c\in P(c)$

Hence we can conclude:

$C\subseteq P\bigcup_{c\in C}{c}$

By axiom of extensionality that $\bigcup_{c\in C}$ is the smallest set whose powerset includes $C$
.